# Saving a One To Many Relationship in CoreData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have created a core data model that has two entities which have a one to many relationship. The entities are Exams and Questions. An Exam can have many questions.

What is the best way to save the Questions entities so they would be associated with the specific Exam?

The flow I want it to have is to start a new exam with an exam name, then add questions, then close out the exam with the questions count and save it to the persistent store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating a `Question` object, just set its `.exam` property (provided that's the name of the inverse relationship to e.g. `Exam.questions`) to the containing exam object. If you need to order the questions, have a look at ordered relationships (available since Lion / iOS 5) or  [this](http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/comments/per-object_ordered_relationships_using_core_data) or [this](http://niftybean.com/main/blog/17-core-data-and-ordered-reflexive-relationships).

Comment: Order doesn't matter at this point, but as far as the first part of your answer goes, do you have a code sample? I'm finding myself overwhelmed with Core Data.

Comment: I recommend more professionalism in your responses. You are by no means obligated to answer me, and seeing as I have followed all of the tutorials of which none have helped me your response has not helped me at all.

Comment: Then please ask your question more precisely. In the best case, it really is as easy as setting one property to the related object.